# SQL Are these the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Are these the same?

```
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportingLevels rl ON e.ei_CompanyID = rl.rl_CompanyId
    AND e.ei_Level = rl.rl_index
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @ReportingLevelId rlid
                WHERE rlid.[reportLevelName] = rl.[rl_name])    
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @ReportingLevelId rlid
                WHERE rlid.[companyid] = rl.[rl_CompanyId])
```

And here is the second.

```
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportingLevels rl ON e.ei_CompanyID = rl.rl_CompanyId
    AND e.ei_Level = rl.rl_index
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @ReportingLevelId rlid
                WHERE rlid.[reportLevelName] = rl.[rl_name]
                  AND rlid.[companyid] = rl.[rl_CompanyId]))
```

I am thinking these are the same, but I got a weird result once when I used a similar variation of this.

Comment: It looks like the first case will have three queries and the second has only two. The results might be the same, obtained through different means. Running an execution plan in SQL Server Management Studio might reveal the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not. The first would select a row if rl_name and rl_CompanyId were present in table @ReportingLevelId, but not necessarily in the same row. The second requires those values to be present in the same row.

Comment: So basically in this cas the AND acts as an OR?

Comment: @user380432 - The `EXISTS` just checks to see that any row meets the criteria.  Since the `EXISTS`clauses are not contained in a parentetical block `(...)` they are evaluated separately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on your secound sql, you are using AND instead of OR.You can see the correct above.

```
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportingLevels rl ON e.ei_CompanyID = rl.rl_CompanyId AND e.ei_Level = rl.rl_index
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @ReportingLevelId rlid WHERE rlid.[reportLevelName] = rl.[rl_name] OR rlid.[companyid] = rl.[rl_CompanyId]))
```

Comment: No this is supposed to be an AND

Comment: Incorrect translation. Scenario is companyID never exists, but rl_name always exists. This always results in EXISTS = true.